# Android: Check if Permisson is granted in another Class, not in the MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-permissions

I am new to Android App development and I'd really like to know if there is a way to check in another Class (a Foreground Service that gathers some location data) if the location Permission was given in the Main Activity.

In my main Activity, I am requesting the permission straight upon app start like this:

```
private fun requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            PERMISSION_ID
        )
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_ID) {
            if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Right Permissions Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its working and I can give my app the permission to access the location. To use a function in my other I class, I need to check if the permission was granted, and I do it like this:

```
fun dummy(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
        // do work that needs the location permission
      }
    }
```

However, if I try to execute this function, I get a null pointer reference. What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: Dont start the other class before you checked permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can't request permissions from a Service.  The reason is that when the request permission dialog comes up, the user is naturally going to think it belongs to the foreground app.  THat confusion is why Google doesn't allow it.  My best suggestion would be to launch an Activity that then asks for permission.